# UX designer requirements

Tags: usability

What are the requirements and tools to work in a company as a UX designer?
And
What is the specific function?
So
If i have good experience in usability and ui-ux design, How i can start to become Specialist in UX Designer?

Comment: You clearly don't understand how StackExchange works yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This report hels a lot http://www.nngroup.com/reports/user-experience-careers/ 
This article also helped me http://www.fastcodesign.com/3032719/ui-ux-who-does-what-a-designers-guide-to-the-tech-industry

Answer (score 4):

There are no specific tools to work as an UX Designer. You need to have a good knowledge of Human Computer Interaction, and psychology helps a lot. UX Designer role is about empathy and learning from your users and other people involved in User Design.

User Experience is a very huge topic to cover. Some of the designers do the research and wireframes only. Some of them do every step (from research via usability test to final design). Everything depends where you are working.

For example I don't need to do any research because we've got a huge department for that in our company, and I only need to ask for data...

Ideally you need to understand your users and stakeholders, produce mockups, wireframes based on your research and knowledge, do the usability test and the visual is the final stage of your work (it's often done by Visual (or UI) designers). In simple words - you are responsible for creating a best experience for your users and laying out features/data easily accessible by others.

When it goes to tools and theory you can find a lot at: http://uxdesign.cc/

Comment: Thank you dear for this answer and i am already have good experience and knowledge about users usability, UX and UI design, but my problem in UX design position in companies because I've many offers for this and i am UI designer and developer but i want to change my position because i love it SO i need to if i can do that or no?

Comment: If you know already how usability and UX work then what's the problem with applying? You should have a portfolio of your UX work - not visuals but whole process explaining how did you get there.

Keep in mind that many companies consider UX designers as people that do only mockups, wireframes and flowcharts, so most of the time you won't even have opportunity to do any tests or research on your users.